# Linear factor divides a function

Tags: functions, divisibility

I just came up with a simple question. 
If I have a polynomial function $f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ and I know that when $x_i=x_j, f=0$. Then does it imply $x_i-x_j$ divides $f$ for all $i\neq j$? If yes, why is that?

Comment: Is $f$ a polynomial? If not, how are you defining divisibility?

Comment: To elaborate on @carmichael561 comment, consider $f(x,y) = \sin(x-y)$. Do you define $(x-y) | f(x,y)$ and if so, how?

Comment: Yes f is a polynomial consisting of x1, ..., xn. And then is this true?

Comment: Have you looked at some examples, say with $n=2$? Have you tried to prove it?

Comment: @JohnMartin I tried with some simple examples of polynomials and it seems that it is true, but in fact, I don't know how to give a contradiction. And I couldn't find an approach to the proof. Is the statement true? Could you provide some hint?

Comment: Well, are you familiar with the Hilbert Basis Theorem? My thought is to maybe try induction on the number of variables. Knowing that this is true for $R[x]$ where $R$ is a UFD should be enough by using this (relatively powerful) theorem.